# How to write regular expression in jmeter for multiple <select> tags in one gsp and also identify the tester which tag value will be taken

Tags: html, regex, xpath, jmeter

In my code having two select tags, so please tell me how to write two regular expression for each  tag based on names different in every select tag. So please give me answer as early as possible.

```
<select id="academicYear" name="academicYear">
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>
.
.
.
<select id="institution" name="institution.id">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">CJT ENGINEERING AND TECHNOLOGY</option>
  <option value="2">CJT ENGINEERING AND TECHNOLOGY_CHENNI</option>
  <option value="3">ENGINEERING AND TECHNOLOGY_KERALA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you wanna parse XML using regex?

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) for this purpose.

1. Attach 2 instances of XPath Extractor (1 per ) to the request sampler that returns mentioned above response.

   ```
   ...
   HTTP Request
       XPath Extractor 1
       XPath Extractor 2
   ...
   ```
2. Provide XPath query for each extractor to extract value of the option based on its name, e.g.

   - for the 1st:

     `//select[@id='academicYear']/option[text()='2013']/@value`
   - for the 2nd:

     `//select[@id='institution']/option[text()='CJT ENGINEERING AND TECHNOLOGY']/@value`

   Your XPath query should return value you want to extract.
3. Extracted values will be stored in jmeter variables pointed in 'Reference Name' field of XPath Extractor (e.g. `${academicYear}` and `institution`). So you can use extracted variable in the further requests using this variable.
4. Since you are using XPath Extractor to parse HTML (not XML!..) response ensure that **Use Tidy (tolerant parser)** option is CHECKED (in [XPath Extractor's control panel](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)).